# binary tree segment fault in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to code a binary tree search/insert/print(BFS) functions.
It compiles fine, but I keep getting segment faults when I try to insert new nodes. Consequently, I could not test the print function neither. Any suggestions, lads?
I did code the functions in a separate Binarytree.cpp file, by the way.

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Node{
    int key;
    struct Node* leftNode;
    struct Node* rightNode;
    //C++에서는 struct의 constructor 가능
    Node(int _key){key = _key;};
} Node;

class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        static Node* rootNode;
    public:
        static Node* search(int searchkey){
            Node* curNode = rootNode;
            while (curNode){
                if (searchkey == curNode->key){
                    break;
                } else if (searchkey < curNode->key){
                    curNode = curNode->leftNode;
                } else {
                    curNode = curNode->rightNode;
                }
            } 
            return curNode;
        }

        static bool insert(int insertkey){
            Node* curNode = search(insertkey);
            if (insertkey == search(insertkey)->key){
                cout << "Key already exits" << endl;
                return false;
            }
            if (!rootNode){
                rootNode = new Node(insertkey);
                return true;
            } else {
                Node* newNode = new Node(insertkey);
                newNode = search(insertkey);
                return true;
            }
        }

        static void print(){
            //Node* rootNode = getRoot();
            vector<Node*> v;

            if (rootNode == NULL){
                cout << "Binary tree is empty." << endl;
                return;
            } else {
                v.push_back(rootNode);
                cout << rootNode->key << endl;
            }
            while (!v.empty()){
                Node* temp = v.front();
                v.erase(v.begin());

                if (temp->leftNode){
                    v.push_back(temp->leftNode);
                    cout << temp->leftNode->key << endl;
                }

                if (temp->rightNode){
                    v.push_back(temp->rightNode);
                    cout << temp->rightNode->key << endl;
                }
            } 
        }

};

Node* BinaryTree::rootNode = NULL;

#endif
```

Comment: `Any suggestions, lads?` Debug your code and find out where it is going wrong. Also: change it so `insert` doesn't call `search` twice for the same key - that's going to get slow on big lists. Also, why check the key since `search` does that anyway?

Comment: My guess is `leftNode` and `rightNode` aren't initialized to 0 and so you go wandering off into random memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here in `insert`:

```
Node* curNode = search(insertkey);
```

When you call `insert` the first time, `curNode` will be `NULL`. In the following condition:

```
if (insertkey == search(insertkey)->key){
        cout << "Key already exits" << endl;
        return false;
}
```

you are trying to deference a `NULL` pointer by doing `search(insertkey)->key`. This causes the seg fault.

Here is the output from backtrace in gdb on my machine:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004009a3 in BinaryTree::insert (insertkey=1) at binarytree.h:38
38              if (insertkey == search(insertkey)->key){
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004009a3 in BinaryTree::insert (insertkey=1) at binarytree.h:38
```

A quick way you can fix this is check if the return from `search` is `NULL` first, then move on to other cases.